# Regex to join single chars

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am trying to devise a regex to join any consecutive instances of single chars in a string. Let me give examples:

```
'A B C Industries' => 'ABC Industries'
'Industries A B C' => 'Industries ABC'
'Foo A B C Industries' => 'Foo ABC Industries'
'Foo A B C Industries X Y Z Product' => 'Foo ABC Industries XYZ Product'
```

etc.

The following are the two attempts I have made (both incomplete):

1)

```
''.join(r'(?<=\s\S)\s|(?<=^\S)\s')
```

2)

```
'\S+'.findall()
```

and then loop over the output.

Is there a regex that can do this in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of *Lookahead* and *Lookbehind* and use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for replacement.

```
(?i)(?<=\b[a-z]) (?=[a-z]\b)
```

**Explanation**:

```
(?i)          # set flags for this block (case-insensitive)
(?<=          # look behind to see if there is:
  \b          #   the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
  [a-z]       #   any character of: 'a' to 'z'
)             # end of look-behind
              # ' '
(?=           # look ahead to see if there is:
  [a-z]       #   any character of: 'a' to 'z'
  \b          #   the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
)             # end of look-ahead
```

**Example**:

```
import re

s1 = 'A B C Industries'
s2 = 'Industries A B C'
s3 = 'Foo A B C Industries'
s4 = 'Foo A B C Industries X Y Z Product'
s5 = 'F O O B A R and b a z'

for s in [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5]:
    print re.sub(r'(?i)(?<=\b[a-z]) (?=[a-z]\b)', '', s)
```

**Output**:

```
ABC Industries
Industries ABC
Foo ABC Industries
Foo ABC Industries XYZ Product
FOOBAR and baz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the regex packages search and replace:

```
output = re.sub("(?<!\w{2}) (?!\w{2})", '', input)
```

This replaces spaces that ware surrounded by single characters.

Edit:
I don't use \w+ because in python: 'look-behind requires fixed-width pattern'